# Change textarea value from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, textarea

I have 2 files. a.html and b.html. a.html contains iframe with source b.html and 2 textareas (1 wysiwyg textarea and 1 standard textarea). b.html contain 2 buttons, button 1 to change textarea 1 value and button 2 to change textarea 2 value but button 1 not working.
Please help

a.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('cnt');
});
</script>
  Iframe
<iframe name="ifr" src="b.html" id="ifr" style="width:30%;display:block;"></iframe><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Textarea 1
<textarea name="cnt" cols="30" rows="20" id="cnt"></textarea></td>
    <td valign="top"> Textarea 2<br>
<textarea name="cnt2" cols="30" rows="20" id="cnt2"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

b.html

```
<input type="button" value="texarea 1" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('cnt').value = Math.random() * 100;" />
<input type="button" value="texarea 2" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('cnt2').value = Math.random() * 100;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to:

```
<input type="button" value="texarea 1" onClick="nicEditors.findEditor('cnt').setContent(Math.random() * 100);" />
```

Check the API from `nicEditors`: http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API

Comment: thank you for answer. i was read the API but did not find how to change the value from iframe using parent....

Comment: @AbdulBari okay, when it works pls mark the question as answered